# Imagesharp mutate in F#

Tags: f#, imagesharp

I am trying to use ImageSharp to edit pictures in F#. I'm struggling to get the image mutations working

To do an image mutation in C#, it looks like you just use the [mutate method and a lambda](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/blob/8899f23c1ddf8044d4dea7d5055386f684120761/tests/ImageSharp.Tests/Processing/Processors/ColorMatrix/KodachromeTest.cs#L19):

```
image.Mutate(x => x.Kodachrome())
```

Normally, to change C# lambdas to F#, I would just use anonymous functions, like so:

```
image.Mutate(fun x -> x.Kodachrome())
```

When I do so, I get the following error:

> No overloads match for method 'Mutate'. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window).

It looks like the Mutate method takes an ImageProcessor, but for some reason in F# the compiler can't figure out that the anonymous function is an ImageProcessor. How can I get an image mutation to work in F#?

Comment: Does the `Mutate` method have any overloads?

Comment: I think it's just got one: (extension) Image.Mutate<'TPixel (requires default constructor and value type and 'TPixel :> IPixel<'TPixel> and 'TPixel :> ValueType)>([<ParamArray>] operations: IImageProcessor<'TPixel> []) : unit

Comment: That parameter type looks like an interface, but your C# code is passing a lambda expression. This does not compute. Are you sure that's the only overload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# can automatically convert from an anonymous function (`fun ...`) to a `System.Action<_>`, but only if the types match exactly. Here, they don't, because `Kodachrome()` doesn't return `unit`. So you need to ignore its return value:

```
image.Mutate(fun x -> x.Kodachrome() |> ignore)
```

Comment: F# is weird. Why would it expect a uint?

Comment: I am shocked at how easy of a fix this is!

Comment: @Tarmil Ha, can write the actual library but can't read simple English :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert your F# lambda into an Action explicitly:

```
image.Mutate <| Action<_> (fun x -> x.Kodachrome ())
```